# CodeIgniter "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Tags: php, codeigniter, mime-types, image-uploading

I was searching a lot and found many questions regarding this problem, unfortunately none of answers did help me.

I'm trying to upload a png image, and I'm receiving the following error:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

I was following this CI guide to build my code: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Here is what I got:

view file:

```
[..]
   <?= form_open_multipart() ?>
   <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
   <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="upload" />
   <?= form_close() ?>
[..]
```

My controller:

```
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '100';
    $config['max_width']     = '1024';
    $config['max_height']    = '768';


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $xx = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $mimetype= $xx['upload_data']['file_type'];

        var_dump('Mime: ' . $mimetype);
        var_dump($_FILES);

        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            Notice::add($this->upload->display_errors(), 'error');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
        }
```

As you can see I'm tryin to `var_dump` the mime type and result is empty.

When I do `var_dump($_FILES)` it looks like everything is fine:

```
array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "imageofm.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/php5cDAZJ" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(358) } }
```

Also, I got `'png'  =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png'),` line, in my `config/mimes.php`.

However, it does happend for all images (haven't tried yet other extensions).

I'd appreciate every help attempt.

Answer (score 7):

Just edit the *mimes.php* file in *application/config/mimes.php* and replace the line for the *csv* by this one:

```
'csv' => array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/anytext', 'text/plain', 'text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel')
```

Comment: There goes 10, not my type of file (mp3) but help me solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

Add ‘text/plain’ to the CSV array in config/mimes.php to $mimes arrays

Comment: Thank you - this solved my problem. My problem was related directly to CSV files, with the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the codeigniter 2.1.0 system/libraries/upload.php with 2.1.2 version upload.php library solves the problem. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->library('upload');  

$this->upload->set_allowed_types('*'); 


class MY_Upload extends CI_Upload {  

    function is_allowed_filetype() {  

        if (count($this->allowed_types) == 0 OR ! is_array($this->allowed_types))  
        {  
            $this->set_error('upload_no_file_types');  
            return FALSE;  
        }  

        if (in_array("*", $this->allowed_types))  
        {  
            return TRUE;  
        }  

        $image_types = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpe');  

        foreach ($this->allowed_types as $val)  
        {  
            $mime = $this->mimes_types(strtolower($val));  

            // Images get some additional checks  
            if (in_array($val, $image_types))  
            {  
                if (getimagesize($this->file_temp) === FALSE)  
                {  
                    return FALSE;  
                }  
            }  

            if (is_array($mime))  
            {  
                if (in_array($this->file_type, $mime, TRUE))  
                {  
                    return TRUE;  
                }  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                if ($mime == $this->file_type)  
                {  
                    return TRUE;  
                }  
            }  
        }  

        return FALSE;  

    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to enable `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in **php.ini**

Answer (score 0):

i just add this line in mime.php on line 34 and pptx is now uploading. test it on real server

> 'pptx' =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in my case, I created a blob object from a canvas by `void canvas.toBlob(callback, mimeType, qualityArgument)` method So the blob file does NOT have its real name (which has an extension), it's just only 'blob'. So I have to use the legacy way to upload the file, instead of an 'upload' library:

```
move_uploaded_file ( $file["tmp_name"], $target_file )
```