# codeigniter upload PSD file

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

A am working on a project using codeigniter. Need to upload PSD file. Trying with this code..

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'psd';
```

But the it show as result : **The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**

plesae help me.

Comment: Try this: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/148809/#723876

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078885/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following it accepts all files

$config['allowed_types'] = ' * '  ;

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting $config['allwoed_types']? In the controller or do you have a config/upload.php?

Also check the psd file that you are trying to upload returns a correct mime type.

Check mime types at application/config/mime.php.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more risky method, but in one way more logical method I use is to allowe all types `$config['allowed_types'] = '*';` and simply validate `preg_match("\.psd$", $str_file_name)` before uploading.

All these mime settings in `application/config/mime.php` probably exists for a reason, but it's way too overcomplicated with some file types due to silly many different mime types for some cases.